# Is having a Firefox profile in the Dropbox a good combination?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, sync, dropbox

I was pretty excited to see sites as Lifehacker and such say how Dropbox can also do synchronisation for Firefox for us. It would also allow me to sync extensions and configuration settings.

After moving the profile directory, it turned out that the bandwidth produced was just massive. It turned out my .Dropbox.cache folder became 5GB after a day and often 1200 files were in queue to be uploaded.

Why do many sites promote Firefox with Dropbox? It seems highly unworkable. Are there any users here? It keeps saying `lock.file` cannot be synced and 24/7 trying to upload/download lots and lots of files while browsing. It's hardly effective.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to sync the cache, not the profile.  Are you syncing the Firefox folder from `AppData\Local` instead of `AppData\Roaming`?

Comment: [citation needed]

Comment: I am syncing C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\1.default. Is this wrong?

Comment: @Ignacio: Was that at me or the OP?  @chronoz: That's the correct folder, but I don't see any `lock.file` in my Firefox profile.  There's a `parent.lock`, but that's only there when Firefox is running, and is locked.  Also, my profile folder is < 30 MB.

Comment: @afrazier: The OP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could move the cache by going into the FF config page. Type about:config in the address bar and click the warning button. Right click somewhere on the about:config page and select New string in the context menu. In the first dialog box type browser.cache.disk.parent_directory and click OK. In the next box type the folder where you want to store your cache, e. g. c:\ (FF places the cache folder under the path you enter, in this example the cache folder would be c:\cache). Now you can sync to Dropbox without having to sync the cache folder.
It is strange though that your cache folder isn't under Appdata\Local where it should be. Using my above method you could force it to be placed there.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that Portable edition works best in Dropbox, better than moving your profile. Although both work fine, you should change settings per http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable though, else it will bloat your install and cause conflicted copies. Also install the conflicted copy remover from http://wiki.dropbox.com/DropboxAddons.